# deleting array items react native moves item position

Tags: arrays, react-native

Ok, maybe the title is not very clear, so let me explain.

I am able to add images to an array and display them, drag and drop accros the screen. Now the issue.

For example I have 3 images in the array, positioned them on different locations on the screen. When I delete image 2 (gets deleted indeed), but image 3 gets moved to the position of origional image 2 position, while it should remain on its own position.

How can I do this?

This is the code I use:

```
import StageGesture from '../components/stageGesture';

const [ finalArray, setFinalArray ] = useState([]);

const onRemove = ({ item }) => {
    let imgName = item.imagetitle;

    const newFinalArray = finalArray.filter(finalItem =>  finalItem.imagetitle !== imgName);

    setFinalArray(newFinalArray);
    setArrayLength(newFinalArray);
};

return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1,backgroundColor:'white' }}>
        {finalArray.map((item, i) =>  (
            // setArrayLength(item.length),
            // console.log('item', item),
            <StageGesture id={item.key} xval={item.valX} yval={item.valY} imagetitle={item.imagetitle} stageimage={item.stageimage} parent={id} onPress={() => onRemove({item})} />
        ))}
    </View>
)
```

StageGesture file:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, createRef, useRef } from 'react';
import { 
    TouchableHighlight, 
    Animated,
    PanResponder,
} from 'react-native';
import { Image } from 'react-native-elements';
import ContextMenu from 'react-native-context-menu-view';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const stagesRef = firestore().collection('stages');

const StageGesture = ({id, imagetitle, stageimage, xval, yval, onPress, parent}) => {

    const [ contextMenuOpen, setConextMenuOpen ] = useState(false);
    const [ img, setImg ] = useState('');
    const [ imgTitle, setImgTitle ] = useState('');
    const [ x, setX ] = useState(0);
    const [ y, setY ] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setImg(stageimage);
        setImgTitle(imagetitle);
    }, []);

    const pan = useState(new Animated.ValueXY({x: xval, y: yval}))[0];
    const panResponder = useState(
        PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
            onPanResponderGrant: () => {
                pan.setOffset({
                    x: pan.x._value,
                    y: pan.y._value
                });
                pan.setValue({x: xval, y: yval});
            },
            onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
                [
                    null,
                    { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
                ],
                {useNativeDriver: false}
            ),
            onPanResponderRelease: () => {
                pan.flattenOffset();
                stagesRef.doc(parent).collection('stageimages').doc(id)
            .update({
                    x: pan.x._value,
                    y: pan.y._value,
                }).then(function() {
                
                });
            }
        })
    )[0];
    return (
        <Animated.View
            key={id}
            style={{
                transform: [{ translateX: pan.x }, { translateY: pan.y }],
                alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                // position: 'absolute',
                elevation: 2 
                // left: 20, 
                // top: 40
            }}
            {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
            <ContextMenu actions={[
                {
                    title: `Delete ${imgTitle}`,
                    systemIcon: 'trash',
                    destructive: true,
                },
            ]} onPress={onPress}>
                <TouchableHighlight onLongPress={() => setConextMenuOpen(true)} activeOpacity={0.7} underlayColor="transparent">
                    <Image source={stageimage} style={{height: 100,width: 100}} resizeMode='contain' />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Animated.View>
    );
}

export default StageGesture
```

Comment: how you delete item from array? show us some codes.

Comment: @cybercoder, thanks, I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const newFinalArray = finalArray.filter(finalItem =>  finalItem.imagetitle !== imgName);
```

When you are using filter, you are creating a new array, So in this case you need to use `map` instead of `filter` to replace element with `NULL`.

```js
const newFinalArray = finalArray.map(finalItem =>finalItem.imagetitle !== imgName ? finalItem : null);
```

And check it in render time like this:

```js
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1,backgroundColor:'white' }}>
        {finalArray.map((item, i) =>  {
            return item ? <StageGesture id={item.key} xval={item.valX} yval={item.valY} imagetitle={item.imagetitle} stageimage={item.stageimage} parent={id} onPress={() => onRemove({item})} /> : <EmptyImage>
...
```

> Also you can delete array element using `delete` it will replace
> element with `undefined` or `null` ( test it ).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I do run into another issue with this. When adding a new image to the array (was working fine before). E.g.: I have 2 images in the array, adding a new image, moves image 2 to position of image 3 (the new image). But when I refresh it, it shows correctly. This is btw the code I use to add new images to the array: setFinalArray([...finalArray, {img, imgName}]);